# Log user input and time to text file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been trying to create a HTML form to collect user data and log it into a text file. What do I put inside "store.php" such that a log of the date/time and what was inside the text box is written to a text file inside a dir called "log"?

In addition, how do I use JS (or jQuery) to hide the entire form once the user has clicked done to prevent them from submitting the form again, but still allow them to see the rest of the page?

The existing HTML for the form is:

```
  <form method="post" action="store.php">
   <input placeholder="Name" id="Name" type="text"/><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Done"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You are expected to try and solve your programming problems yourself before asking a question here. Usually trying to break down your problem in to smaller ones can be very helpful in your understanding of what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what happens in store.php you must use PHP's filesystem functions (like fread(), file_get_contents(), file_put_contents(), etc.), open/create a file, write your data into it, close and save it.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

For the JQuery part, look at form events. Simple example:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
   $(this).hide();   
}
```

Or post more code and we can give you a better solution.

edit:
here is a function I pulled from some old project:

```
function write_log( $error,$logtype="error" ) {
// get date and time for the log entry
$t = time();
$date = date('d/n/Y H:i:s', $t);

// prepare log string
$log = "#{$date} : {$error}<br>\n";

// decide what type of log to write to
$type = $logtype;    
switch($logtype) {
    case("error"):
        $type = "errors";
        break;
    case("user"):
        $type = "users";
        break;
    case("db"):
        $type = "db";
        break;
}
$log = trim( $log );    
$filename = LOG_PATH."/{$type}_log.txt";  
file_put_contents($filename, $log, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );       
}// end of function
```

It's the same. First parameter takes log content, second optional parameter takes log type (or defaults to 'error')

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd say this question is too broad to be  answerable. Your answer assumes that OP is using ajax to submit the form data, otherwise your code would only hide the form until the page is redirected. We don't know what OP has tried (if anything) though.

Comment: I agree. We can only assume with so little info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHPs `fread` and `fwrite` functions.
In order to hide the form you'll first need to disable the forms default action, then pass the parameters through AJAX and then hide it.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(...)
    .done(function(){
        $("#myForm").fadeOut();
    });
});
```